# Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader

Tags: c#, wpf, memorystream

I have server and client application and they are communicating over NetworkStream. On server I binary serialize an object and send it over NetworkStream, it is read on client and deserialized. But it throws and error:
Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
First I checked the length of NetworkStream and it is the same on server and client after sending the serialized object. Then I add a server reference to client and use Server.SaveData to be sure I have exactly the same class when deserializing.

Then I tried serializing and deserializing then same object on server and code below works perfectly.

```
stream.Read(buffer, 0, total);
network_stream.Write(buffer, 0, total);

network_stream.Read(buffer, 0, total);
stream.Position = 0;
stream.Write(buffer, 0, total);

SaveData savedata = (SaveData)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

Here's full code from server:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

current_state.saveData(map, red, blu);
formatter.Serialize(stream, current_state);

int total = (int)stream.Length;
byte[] buffer = new byte[total];

writer.WriteLine(total.ToString());
writer.Flush();

stream.Read(buffer, 0, total);
network_stream.Write(buffer, 0, total);

stream.Close();
```

And client side:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

while (reader.Peek() == '\0') { reader.Read(); } //solved the problem, idkw
int total = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine().ToString());
byte[] buffer = new byte[total];

network_stream.Read(buffer, 0, total);
stream.Position = 0;
stream.Write(buffer, 0, total);
stream.Position = 0;

Console.Write(stream.Length.ToString());

Server.SaveData current_state = (Server.SaveData)formatter.Deserialize(stream); //here is the problem

stream.Close();
```

Comment: Are you unable to deserialize data with `BinaryFormatter` serialized by another application or do you have problems to deliver serialized binary stream or what?

Comment: Client and server using the same version of .net?

Comment: also, is this a UDP or TCP based stream? are you sure the complete set of data is there on the receive side?

Comment: Please see my answer. Looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Why not serialize/deserialize the data directly to the `NetworkStream` (without intermediate `MemoryStream`)?

A little example.

Assume, there is a data structure that the server and the client use to exchange with (in your case the data structure is `current_state`).

```
[Serializable]
public class UserData : ISerializable
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public UserData(string text, int number)
    {
        Text = text;
        Number = number;
    }

    protected UserData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Text = info.GetString("Text");
        Number = info.GetInt32("Number");
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Text", Text);
        info.AddValue("Number", Number);
    }
}
```

To send the data structure (from the client side, for example):

```
using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
{
    var userData = new UserData("Hello.", 9);

    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(networkStream, userData);
}
```

To receive the data structure (server side, for example):

```
var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
{
    while (networkStream.DataAvailable)
    {
        var receivedData = (UserData)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(networkStream);
    }
}
```